# Python-PPTX: How to set font properties of each individual entry in a legend?

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I have an XY-Scatter chart made using Python-PPTX with a legend on the right side. I need to change the font color of individual legend entries based on certain criteria.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: @wayfare You can do this by adding a javascript function in labelFormatter property of the legend. This javascript contains the logic to be used to create the HTML for each individual legend item. Here's an example - https://jsfiddle.net/379k5yrs/156/ . Hope this helps.  

Also, what I've been struggling with is, sending this javascript function when using the Highcharts export server. The input you send to the export server must be in pure JSON format, and the JS function element disturbs that and causes an error. Stringified version of the function too throws an error.

Comment: How is this related to python-pptx?

Comment: Oh God! My mistake. My project involved Highcharts in parallel with Python-PPTX. I got so engrossed in the 'manipulating legend' aspect, I forgot you were asking about python-pptx. Unfortunately, I haven't come across a solution for python-pptx yet.